# Does Windows Embedded OS supports Microsoft Bitlocker?

Tags: bitlocker

Does Windows Embedded OS supports Microsoft Bitlocker? If yes what are the list of versions and does the windows embedded OS comes with bitlocker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitlocker is a Windows Embedded Standard 7 feature included is a feature pack.  For details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794262%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx